# It is possible to obtain some concrete data using the generic view `ListView`?

Tags: python, django, django-views

It is possible to obtain some concrete data using the generic view `ListView`? I know how to do it creating my own function, but actually I'm using a `ListView` to show some data and now, I just simply need to know the value of the last row from one column called data_id.

This my actual class:

```
class devData_bbdd_view(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'data_app/data-bbdd.html'
    paginate_by = 50
    queryset = DevData.objects.order_by('-data_timestamp')
    context_object_name = 'DevDataList'
    login_url = reverse_lazy('user_app:login')
```

I thought maybe I can do something like

```
last_row = queryset[-1]
```

And from here obtain the the value of the data_id, but it's totally wrong.

I suppose I can seriealize the queryset and then do it, but I suppose too is not the best option. How can I do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that you can't use negative indexes for Django querysets (e.g. `[-1]`), unless you convert it to a list first, e.g. `list(queryset)[-1]`. But you can't do this in the class, it needs to go in a method. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

All of the code in your view runs when the module loads. If you want to access the database, you need to do it inside a method that runs when Django handles the request.

For example, you could override `get_context_data`, fetch the last row of the queryset and add `data_id` to the template context as follows:

```
class devData_bbdd_view(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'data_app/data-bbdd.html'
    paginate_by = 50
    queryset = DevData.objects.order_by('-data_timestamp')
    context_object_name = 'DevDataList'
    login_url = reverse_lazy('user_app:login')

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        last_row = self.queryset.last()
        context['data_id'] = last_row.data_id
        return context
```

Then in the template you can use `{{ data_id }}`.

As Sumedh pointed out, you are already reversing the queryset with `order_by('-data_timestamp')`, so double check that you want to use `last()` and not `first()`.

Comment: Thank you! And I know the pointing, I want the last from queryset that obviously is the first one from the model.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have fetched the query in descending order by "data_timestamp", if you meant last row while ordering by timestamp then, lastrow = queryset[0] or lastrow = queryset.first() might give you the desired result.